# jQuery preload and PHP Framework (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, preload

I'm learning CodeIgniter, I need to know how to write a jQuery code inside it BUT my problem is how to write the jQuery code in the right way too.

I thought I have to write just ONE SINGLE file full of action for classes and IDs (ecc) and make CI load it at EVERY page, but this will slow down my App as every time I change page I have a new reload of the JS file.

So I thought I can write multiple files based on the page loaded, but I'd risk of having to re-write actions for some classes (Home has its own JS file and a button classed 'X', the page About has the same button but in this case a different JS file so the jQuery function for X is written twice in two different JS).

My question in therefore multiple:

1. Is there a way of preloading a jQuery file in CI so that I make a preload in my App @ start and than that is cached and don't need to reload it?
2. Or is there another way to bypass this problem?

Comment: IMHO the client's browser doesn't download everytime the javascript/jquery (and other) files - browser does the caching. Create a simple html page and a simple javascript, load it into a browser, open firebug(-like app), reload your page and see that doesn't download again your seperate files.

So I think you can put your javascript (jquery) codes into a seperate js file.

Comment: OK. Let's say I have a big JS file/s and I want to preload it. I can use document.load and show a preload, but next page load I have the preload again.... Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Do you want load same JS file in many htmls? I think browser will load from cache again - same filename, same size, same timestamp... I think the cache method is clever :) :)
Just test it with firebug and you'll see it!

Comment: Sorry, my english sucks... I meant if I make a preloader bar in jQuery and show it before the whole app loads, loading the jQuery from cache will show the preloader bar @ every page-load. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: My english sucks too :) Don't you want to show a loader bar? Do you have a js which shows a loader bar, yes? Where is this function? Maybe you can put this routin into another file and include this file if you want to show a bar.